# Hg-git - No module named ordereddict

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

I think I have installed Hg-Git correctly however when I try to push to a Git server it throws this error:

```
No module named ordereddict
```

What is the cause of this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the `ordereddict` module cannot be found. [This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) is probably the one being referenced.

You may be able to fix the error by installing the third-party module linked above, likely via your operating system's package manager or via `pip`, depending on your needs.

Python has natively had an ordered dictionary type since version 2.7, so you may also be able to fix it by upgrading your Python to 2.7, but this will only work if the code is designed to use the native class if it is available.

Comment: I think hg-git recently moved to requiring python2.7.